# How do I setup connection to a Redshift cluster inside a VPC?

Tags: security, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-redshift

I createad a Redshift cluster inside a Public subnet inside a VPC. The VPC is connected to an Internet Gateway

Configured IPs for inbound/oubound traffic in cluster security group.
Configured IPs for inbound/oubound traffic in VPC security group.
Configured IPs for inbound/oubound traffic in Network ACL.
Configured IPs for inbound/oubound traffic in Main route table.
Still when I try to connect using a client, I get connection refused. Am I missing step here ?

Comment: any update on this?